# Text::CSV parsing when data contains newline

Tags: perl, csv

I have a code that  parses a csv file and the data also contains newline. 
But Text::CSV breaks when it encounters "\n" inside the data

This is the parse code

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary=> 1, eol => $/, allow_loose_quotes => 1, allow_loose_escapes=> 1 }) || die $!;
#print Dumper($csv);                                                                                                                           

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $csv_handle,  $file  or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($csv_handle)) {
    print Dumper($row);
}
```

This is the data

```
196766,31,"MR SRINIVASALU LAKSHMIPATHY\"DEC\"\
\"71"
196766,56,"255233.47"
```

Comment: Does the data need to contain newlines? Could you just `s/\n//;`?

Comment: Almost... try `s/\\\n//sg;`

Comment: No, I dont want to lose the newline in the data

Comment: Works here for me. You'll probably need to specify what platform you are on, what version of Text::CSV and whether it's the pure-perl or XS version. Oh, and whether the file has the same line-endings as your perl OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the `escape_char` to `\`, as it defaults to `"`. However, this doesn't fix the problem if you run the pure-perl version of `Text::CSV`. With the XS version (`Text::CSV_XS`), this works:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary => 1,
    eol => "\n",
    quote_char => '"',
    escape_char => '\\',
    auto_diag => 2,
    allow_loose_escapes => 1,
}) or die "Can't create CSV parser";

while( my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA) ) {
    print Dumper $row;
}

__DATA__
1,"2
",3
196766,31,"MR SRINIVASALU LAKSHMIPATHY\"DEC\"\
\"71"
196766,56,"255233.47"
```

The pure-Perl parser fails on the 2nd record and complains about a missing closing quote. If we set `allow_loose_quotes` to a true value, then the CSV parses, but the 2nd record is split apart (a third record with a sole field containing `\"71"` is inserted). The XS version does not show this behaviour.

This looks like a bug in Text::CSV_PP.