# perl Text::CSV_XS removes all escape_chars

Tags: perl, csv, xs

I had moved from Text::CSV to the XS version because of a problem of newline inside data
[Text::CSV parsing when data contains newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485762/textcsv-parsing-when-data-contains-newline)

Text::CSV_XS removes all the escape chars in the data 
( I am using linux with perl 5.8.8 ) 
This is the sample code (below)

I expect that the attribute on the 3 row should be \N after escaping 1 \ but Text::CSV_XS removes both the \

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    binary => 1,
    eol => "\n",
    quote_char => '"',
    escape_char => '\\',
    auto_diag => 2,
    allow_loose_escapes => 1,
}) or die "Can't create CSV parser";

while( my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA) ) {
    print join(" ",@{$row})."\n";
}

__DATA__
ata,atb,atc
1a,"1b                                                                                                                                         
1b-continued",1c
\\N,2b,2c
```

This is the output

```
ata atb atc
1a 1b
1b-continued 1c
N 2b 2c
```

Comment: It only removes the backslashes if you set `escape_char => '\\'`. I am wondering if you have not misunderstood what that option does.

Answer (score 1):

Use `allow_unquoted_escape => 1` (available since version 0.95).

Comment: I think this parameter is not implemented in the XS module 
I get this error
`


`
     # CSV_XS ERROR: 1000 - INI - Unknown attribute
    'allow_unquoted_escape' @ pos 0
     Can't create CSV parser at parse1 line 6.

Comment: You must have an older version